# Piecing together an equivalent of Google's Data Science / Engineering AIY Computer Viz kit

Tags: computer-vision, google

Google has a DS / AI / ML / engineering themed [DIY kit](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/vision) for voice recognition and computer vision.

[image]

The big manufacturers (Micro Center, Mouser, Seeed, etc) who partnered with Google are sold out and currently don't list any future availability dates.

These projects are kind of [publicity](https://liliputing.com/2017/11/google-introduces-45-aiy-vision-kit-diy-computer-vision-hardware-projects.html), goodwill, and community-engagement efforts by Google, very much in the vein of Google Cardboard. They're meant to be cheap, accessible, and easily cloned for popular use.

All of that is great and it's an attractive hobby for a Data Scientist, but the problem is that Supply < Demand due to low manufacturer price points (part of an agreement with Google to limit [quantity](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10192/what-does-quantity-represent-when-looking-at-supply-and-demand) of supply whilst simultaneously restraining price, thus resulting in a shortage). As a result, we are now getting price gouged on eBay by resellers for >$250/each.

[image]

Unlike with [Google Cardboard](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/), most of the businesses that might clone and sell their versions of it have not yet gotten into the game (to my knowledge).

Is it possible to piece together a list of what you'd need to buy to make your own?

Here's what I have so far. Some of this (the Pi) was meant to be purchased separately anyway:

1. [Raspberry Pi Zero W board](http://www.microcenter.com/product/463611/8MP_Raspberry_Pi_Camera_Module)
2. [Raspberry Pi Camera 2](http://www.microcenter.com/product/463611/8MP_Raspberry_Pi_Camera_Module)
3. Raspberry Pi Zero W compatible power supply (SKU: 001917)
4. Micro SD card (available everywhere offline and online)
5. Cardboard (I have questions on this below)
6. [Piezo buzzer](https://www.radioshack.com/products/radioshack-108db-piezo-buzzer?gclid=CjwKCAiA8P_TBRA9EiwAJrpHM9Zr8NPDAQWFhqagk31u0KaVHM322v65YO5t8oCs6ZWj4Wsn7DpSrhoCGa8QAvD_BwE)

For the cardboard are there any CNC files or do you just transcript/print their design and manually cut your own? For now I'll start with a cereal box or something and cut it to approx. that size.

What about the button and status LED? Can we find the same or sufficiently similar sold separately such that one could follow along with Google AIY projects, or demo projects for AIY users to replicate?

[image]

Not yet located:

1. VisionBonnet accessory board (×1)
2. 11mm plastic standoffs (×2)
3. 24mm RGB arcade button and nut (×1)
4. Privacy LED (×1)
5. LED bezel (×1)
6. Tripod mounting nut (×1)
7. Lens, lens washer (1 spare), and lens magnet (×1)
8. Button harness (×1)
9. Pi0 camera flat flex cable (×1)
10. MIPI flat flex cable (×1) ... is [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-W-Camera-Cable-30-CM-Ribbon-Line-FFC-Cable-for-Raspberry-Pi-Zero/32820946214.html?src=google&albslr=221224290&isdl=y&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&source=%7Bifdyn:dyn%7D%7Bifpla:pla%7D%7Bifdbm:DBM&albch=DID%7D&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=708-803-3821&isdl=y&albcp=653153647&albag=34728528644&slnk=&trgt=75384829977&plac=&crea=en32820946214&netw=g&device=c&mtctp=&gclid=CjwKCAiA8P_TBRA9EiwAJrpHMxY0IDssMiq9fJq668sZ3pmSrUwgaMpmDRcF6dQU6bniIjX6Yp3BARoCzYoQAvD_BwE) is?
11. External cardboard box (×1)
12. Internal cardboard frame (×1)